# Are there any other ways to get KI Gold?

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

Rather than **paying** to get them, is there a way to farm or earn KI gold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. KI Gold(which is the same name as another game in the franchise, poor showing by Microsoft) must be paid for as it's simply a microtransaction feature. However, you can earn pretty much, if not all of the things you can buy with KI Gold.

Comment: Yeah the only thing I'm really after are the fighters.